# PJSIP: Error file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, voip, pjsip

I working on Project a project to make an iOS App to work like `Viber/Skype` using VoIP Protocol. For this I am using  `pjsip SDK` but I get some Error :(

File not found, 
unknown type name, etc

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon your screenshot,you have renamed the sample files in pjsipapp.but you have not configured the header paths and libarary paths.
In your target click build settings and in search paths add your library paths.Hope it helps

[image]

Comment: please guide me how do I add proper header path according to my system, I have never done this before.